# Prove $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is approximated by $\frac{y(x+h)-y(x-h)}{2h}$ to $O(h^2)$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I tried to solve it by truncating the Taylor series expansions for $y(x+h)$ and $y(x-h)$ but I couldn't find a way to relate it to the derivative. I wasn't sure where the appropriate place to truncate was so I tried using 2nd order Taylor polynomials. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y$ is twice differentiable,

$$y(x+h)=y(x)+hy'(x)+O(h^2)$$
$$y(x-h)=y(x)-hy'(x)+O(h^2)$$
Subtract
$$(y(x+h)-y(x-h))=2hy'(x)+O(h^2)$$
$$\frac{y(x+h)-y(x-h)}{2h}=y'(x)+O(h)$$
And the approximation is to $O(h)$ (actually, you can get $o(h)$ in this case, using Taylor-Young formula, but not $O(h^2)$).

However, if $y$ has a third derivative,

$$y(x+h)=y(x)+hy'(x)+\frac12h^2y''(x)+O(h^3)$$
$$y(x+h)=y(x)-hy'(x)+\frac12h^2y''(x)+O(h^3)$$
Subtract
$$(y(x+h)-y(x-h))=2hy'(x)+O(h^3)$$
$$\frac{y(x+h)-y(x-h)}{2h}=y'(x)+O(h^2)$$
And then the approximation is to $O(h^2)$.

Comment: Woah, you type fast!

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Use your formula for $y(x+t)$ at the order $3$ to obtain $O(h^2)$.

Comment: @Kelenner Yes, I just thought about it. :-)

Comment: @Kelenner so you include $\frac{h^2}{2}y''(x)$ in the Taylor series?

Comment: @user172659 Yes, the $y''$ terms vanish.

Comment: @user: Yes: since you're seeking a first-order approximation, you have to expand the numerator to a second-order approximation, because dividing by $h$ reduces the order by $1$: i.e. $O(h^3) / h = O(h^2)$.